# Slick2d | Best way to render & update

Tags: java, render, solution, slick2d

### The problem:

What do you think what is the best way to render and update entities? 
Currently im using a world class to do this.

**Links:**

> [***The game (finished)***](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhvf5vbqj25sgyw/game.jar)

**The code (from World.java):**

```
List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g, Camera camera) {
    // Draw background
    background.draw(0 - camera.getX(), 0 - camera.getY(), 2100, 2100);

    // Loop through all entities and render
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
        Entity entity = entities.get(i);

        // A very long if... render only if visible
        if (entity.getX() < player.getX() + ((gc.getWidth() / 2) + entity.getWidth() + 50) &&
            entity.getX() > player.getX() - ((gc.getWidth() / 2) + entity.getWidth() + 50) &&
            entity.getY() < player.getY() + ((gc.getHeight() / 2) + entity.getHeight() + 50) &&
            entity.getY() > player.getY() - ((gc.getHeight() / 2) + entity.getHeight() + 50)) {
                entity.render(gc, g);
            }
        }
    }


    public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {
        // Loop through entities and update all time
        for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
            Entity entity = entities.get(i);
            entity.update(gc, delta);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g, Camera camera) {
   background.draw(0 - camera.getX(), 0 - camera.getY(), 2100, 2100);
   for( Entity entity : entities ) {
      if( entity.isVisible( player, gc )) {
         entity.render( gc, g );
      }
   }
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {
   for( Entity entity : entities ) {
      entity.update( gc, delta );
   }
}
```

`Entity.update()` should not modify the list, in place use:

```
private final List< Entity > toBeRemoved = new LinkedList<>();

public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) {
   toBeRemoved.clear();
   for( Entity entity : entities ) {
      if( entity.update( gc, delta )) {
         toBeRemoved.add( entity );
      }
   }
   entities.removeAll( toBeRemoved );
}
```

`Entity.update()` return true when the entity need removal.

Comment: I've got error when I add a new element to the list entities.

Comment: Please open a new question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), with a full stack error

Comment: Don't use the shortened for loop for the update void. You'll get a concurrent modification exception.

Comment: @BenPoulson thanks, but why can I use it in the render method?

Comment: @HUNeater Because you can't make changes to an object while you're still reading from it in that style of for loop. That's why you get the  concurrent modification exception. However, in the render loop, you're not writing changes to the object, so no errors.

Comment: @Ben Poulson: solution added to handle concurrent modification exception.